# Recursive filling the select fields with options from array in JavaScript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, recursion

I have some data in a JavaScript object and need to recursively insert it into the select fields. The problem is that the original page doesn't load via AJAX etc., but loads the whole data into the DOM directly. Therefore until the page is loaded we don't know, how many child levels there'll be, so a recursive algorithm is needed

Please, consider the following example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var jsonData = {
    "1": {
      "uid": 1,
      "value": "foo1",
      "label": "FOO1",
      "children": {
        "2": {
          "uid": 2,
          "value": "foo1a",
          "label": "FOO1a",
          "parent": 1
        },
        "3": {
          "uid": 3,
          "value": "foo1b",
          "label": "FOO1b",
          "parent": 1
        },
        "4": {
          "uid": 4,
          "value": "foo1c",
          "label": "FOO1c",
          "parent": 1
        }
      }
    },
    "5": {
      "uid": 5,
      "value": "foo2",
      "label": "FOO2",
      "children": {
        "6": {
          "uid": 6,
          "value": "foo2a",
          "label": "FOO2a",
          "parent": 5,
          "children": {
            "7": {
              "uid": 7,
              "value": "foo2a1a",
              "label": "FOO2a1a",
              "parent": 6,
              "children": {
                "8": {
                  "uid": 8,
                  "value": "foo2a1a1a",
                  "label": "FOO2a1a1a",
                  "parent": 7
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };

  // works only for the 1st select field for now...
  // should fill the other fields with children options dependent on the selection in the 1st field
  $(jsonData).each(function() {
    $.each(jsonData, function(i) {
      $('#singleselect-subject-1').append(
        '<option value="' + jsonData[i].value + '" ' +
        '        data-uid="' + jsonData[i].uid + '">' + jsonData[i].label +
        '</option>'
      );
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select optiondatasource="singleselect-subject-data" optiondatasourcefieldposition="1" id="singleselect-subject-1"></select>
<select optiondatasource="singleselect-subject-data" optiondatasourcefieldposition="1" id="singleselect-subject-2"></select>
<select optiondatasource="singleselect-subject-data" optiondatasourcefieldposition="1" id="singleselect-subject-3"></select>
```

Do you have an idea, how to make this recursion in JavaScript to work? jQuery3 is present in the project and thus can (and actually should) be used, where possible and where it makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have control over the format of the object? There are ***much*** easier ways to do this if you can change it

Comment: The object comes as is, but I‘m generally free to modify it before populating the select fields.

Comment: Initially, I'm leaning towards the notion, "structure the data first, then write out the UI elements and apply the data", as opposed to the idea of trying to do both of them at the same time.

Comment: I'm unclear as to the final presentation you want. "1" seems pretty clear ("1" is the ui component and its three children are options). Would "5" contain as options all its children (so 5 is the UI component and all the children are options)? "6" has a child, "7" has a child, and "8" does not. How many UI components should this data render total? If you can answer that clearly, I'm pretty sure I have something that would work.